# Android C2DM server side issues

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am developing a server side app to communicate with an android app that is ready for C2DM.  The author or the device side app gave me a Google auth token that I use to send messages and that works fine.  I am trying to send messages with a different email account than the one he provided so I did the following:

1. signed up for an account
2. recevied an email saying I have been whitelisted
3. found code to generate an auth token based on a email address and password
4. used that new auth token to send messages
5. I get Invalid Registration when I send messages with this other auth token

My question is, is the problem that my email account isn't the account that developed the app?  If I wanted to send the example code to other folks would I need to hide the auth token?

I was trying to have the people I hand the server app to enter thier own white listed account, generate an auth token and send messages to the device.  I guess I am missing something.

Lastly, I see the device has a registrationID.  I am sending that in the message along with some text.  Like I said, I see the text on the device with the original Auth Token.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 0):

Your email address is used in two places:

1. The device uses it to request a registration id.
2. The server app uses it to get an auth token.

These two email addresses have to be the same! Otherwise you get a Invalid Registration response.

Your client can give you this mail address, since it is only meant as a role account, so there shouldn't be any mail in it.

Normally when you pass your code to another developer / on a forum etc, you just write down a part of the auth token (e.g. AuthToken=fejwio23j23i...hweiofWE3).